# force typescript class method to be unary method with an argument of a specific type

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

For fun I wanted to see if I could come up with a way, using just types, that would force all functions in a class to be a unary function that takes any object so long as that object conforms to a specified interface (in this case I wanted to make sure a `ContextObj` was provided as the argument)

I took a stab at it like this:

```
interface BaseContext {}
interface SomeContext { foo: 'lish'; };
interface ContextObj<T> { context: T }

// a unary function that takes an argument that conforms to the ContextObj interface
// and returns a value of type U
type ContextFn<T, U> = (x: ContextObj<T>)  => U;

// a type to represent any function
type AnyFunction = (...args: any[]) => any;

// we use mapped types and conditional types here to determine if
// T[K], the value of the property K on type T, is a function
// if it's not a function we return the T[K] unaltered
// if it is a function we make sure it conforms to our ContextFn type
// otherwise we return never which I was hoping would result in an error
type ContextService<T, U extends BaseContext> = {
  [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends AnyFunction
  ? T[K] extends ContextFn<U, ReturnType<T[K]>>
    ? T[K]
    : never
  : T[K]
};

class BarService implements ContextService<BarService, SomeContext> {
  test:string = 'test';
  // expected error: not assignable to type never
  updateBar(): string {
    return '';
  }
}
```

It turns out this did not work as expected as it is a limit (or feature?) of TypeScript: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-are-functions-with-fewer-parameters-assignable-to-functions-that-take-more-parameters

I'm curious if there's a way to do something like this (force method arguments to match to specific type signatures) at the class or interface level? Can it be done at the individual method level via a decorator (granted at that point you might as well just use a proper type signature).

Just testing out the limits :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to add another condition for the length of the parameters. You can extract the type of the parameters as a tuple using `Parameters`. The tuple will have a length property that is of a number literal type, so you can check that the `length` extends `1`:

```
type ContextService<T, U extends BaseContext> = {
    [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends AnyFunction ?
        T[K] extends ContextFn<U, ReturnType<T[K]>> ?
            Parameters<T[K]>["length"] extends 1 ? T[K]
        : never : never
    : T[K]
};

class BarService implements ContextService<BarService, SomeContext> {
    test: string = 'test';
    // error: not assignable to type never
    updateBar(): string {
        return '';
    }
    updateBar2(p: ContextObj<SomeContext>): string { // ok
        return '';
    }
}
```

Might be useful to give a hint to the user as to the problem, athough custom errors are not supported, this will be pretty close:

```
type ContextService<T, U extends BaseContext> = {
    [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends AnyFunction ?
        T[K] extends ContextFn<U, ReturnType<T[K]>> ?
            Parameters<T[K]>["length"] extends 1 ? T[K]
        : ["Method must have exactly one parameter of type ", ContextObj<U>, "Found Parameters:", Parameters<T[K]>] 
        : ["Parameters types not macthed, expected  [", ContextObj<U>, "] Found Parameters:", Parameters<T[K]>]
    : T[K]
};

class BarService implements ContextService<BarService, SomeContext> {
    test: string = 'test';
    // error: not assignable to type never
    updateBar(): string {// Type '() => string' is missing the following properties from type '["Method must have exactly one parameter of type ", ContextObj<SomeContext>, "Found Parameters:", []]'
        return '';
    }
    updateBar2(p: ContextObj<SomeContext>): string {
        return '';
    }

    updateBar3(p: SomeContext): string { // Type '(p: SomeContext) => string' is missing the following properties from type '["Parameters types not macthed, expected  [", ContextObj<SomeContext>, "] Found Parameters:", [SomeContext]]'
        return '';
    }
}
```

**Edit**

Answering comment question: Can this be done with decorators ?

Answer is yes, we can capture as type parameters the class the decorator is being applied to as well as the key it is applied to and use the same logic as we did for a property key previously. Just that this time we attach the error to the key passed into the decorator:

```
type Check<TSig extends (...a: any[]) => any, T, K extends keyof T> = 
    T[K] extends (...a: any[]) => any ?
    T[K] extends TSig ?
            Parameters<T[K]>["length"] extends 1 ? unknown
        : ["Method must have exactly one parameter of type ", Parameters<TSig>, "Found Parameters:", Parameters<T[K]>] 
        : ["Parameters types not macthed, expected  [", Parameters<TSig>, "] Found Parameters:", Parameters<T[K]>]
    : unknown
function ensureSignatire<TSig extends (...a: any[]) => any>() {
    return function <TTarget, TKey extends keyof TTarget>(target: TTarget, key: TKey & Check<TSig, TTarget, TKey>) {

    }
}

class BarService {
    test: string = 'test';

    @ensureSignatire<ContextFn<SomeContext, any>>() // Type '"updateBar"' is not assignable to type '["Method must have exactly one parameter of type ", [ContextObj<SomeContext>], "Found Parameters:", []]'.
    updateBar(): string {
        return '';
    }

    @ensureSignatire<ContextFn<SomeContext, any>>() //ok
    updateBar2(p: ContextObj<SomeContext>): string {
        return '';
    }
    @ensureSignatire<ContextFn<SomeContext, any>>() //  Type '"updateBar3"' is not assignable to type '["Parameters types not macthed, expected  [", [ContextObj<SomeContext>], "] Found Parameters:", [SomeContext]]'
    updateBar3(p: SomeContext): string { 
        return '';
    }
}
```

Comment: The typescript king returns! I was wondering if there was a way to use `infer` here! Didn't realize you could do that `extends 1` on the length! Is it possible to do something like this on individual methods via an attribute?

Comment: @Jordan I never left ;-). I am not sure about the weather it is possible from a decorator, I'll check tomorrow.

Comment: @Jordan added decorator version

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir this is an awsome ansear! The thing is it doesnt work for private methods (in the decorator example) as they are not part of the target type and as such the check fails. any suggestions?

Comment: @regevbr no sorry, private members do not show up in `keyof` so there is nothing we can really do to constrain privates in this way.